# List of relase dates and prices of Adobe products?

Tags: data-request, prices, software

Not sure if this belongs here, but I'm looking for a complete list of all versions of the Adobe Creative Suite that contains exact release dates and the original prices. Would be nice if it contained information about discounts for students, special offers and options to buy single products as well.

Is there an overview or a repository that contains this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get release dates of versions/iterations at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Creative_Suite but I think you'll need to use a combination of Google and [The Wayback Machine by archive.org](https://archive.org/web/) to find pricing.

Also see http://www.computerworld.com/article/2517120/enterprise-applications/adobe-creative-suite--the-history.html

Comment: wayback machine is a god send